# Spark streaming consumer streams null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I have created a kafka producer using node js which is basically pushing the live data it is receiving from upstox into a kafka-topic. The kafka-producer snippet looks someting like this:

```
upstox.on("liveFeed", function(message) {
            //message for live feed 
            var data = JSON.stringify(message);
            var payload = [{
                topic : 'live-feed',
                message: data,
                attributes: 1
            }];

            producer.send(payload, function(error, result) {
               console.info('Sent payload to Kafka: ', payload);
               if (error) {
                 console.error(error);
               } else {
                 console.log('result: ', result)
               }
  });
```

It's giving me the live feed in the following format:

```
topic: live-feed,
message:{live-feed data},
attributes:1
```

Now I'm trying to code a spark streaming consumer which streams the data produced by this producer. I came up with something like this:

```
package com.senpuja.datastream

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object LiveFeedStream {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val brokers = util.Try(args(0)).getOrElse("localhost:9092")
val inTopic = util.Try(args(1)).getOrElse("live-feed")

val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val spark = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val streamCtx = new StreamingContext(spark, Seconds(10))


val inTopicSet = Set(inTopic)
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> brokers,
  "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
)

val msg = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  streamCtx,
  kafkaParams,
  inTopicSet
)

msg.print()

streamCtx.start()
streamCtx.awaitTermination()}
```

But when I submit the code, I get the following output which is just null:

```
{null}, {null}
{null}, {null}
{null}, {null}
{null}, {null}
{null}, {null}
```

I want to retrieve the message part from the producer topic. I think it has something to do with the key-value thing I guess, but I'm not able to figure out its solution. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add enable.auto.commit = false in Kafka parameter and try.

Comment: It seems that because I passed the message only, this error had occurred. I used the KeyedMessage in the kafka producer and now the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was this that I was directly passing the message while the spark streaming code was looking for a key-value pair. So I used KeyedMessage to produce a key-value pair.

```
upstox.on("liveFeed", function(message) {
            //message for live feed var 
            var data = JSON.stringify(message);
            var km = new KeyedMessage(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000), data);
            var payload = [{
                topic : 'live-feed',
                messages: km
            }];

producer.send(payload, function(error, result) {
    console.info('Sent payload to Kafka: ', payload);
    if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    } else {
    console.log('result: ', result)
    }
    )}
```

It solved my problem.